# Diferentes fallos - expected errors c++

Tags: c++

Estes es un proyecto escolar para demostrar los metodos de busqueda y ordenacion en C++.

Ya se diseño el menu, sus respectivos cases usando switch. En general el programa funcionaba correctamente pero al momento de agregar el codigo de el case 3 me marca diversos errores como } faltantes o ; al final de alguna linea. Ese elemento por separado compila y corre sin problemas, y este codigo sin esa porcion del codigo compila y corre sin problemas. He revisado el codigo por si tengo algun faltante pero nada de eso. Alguna ayuda para saber que podria estar omitiendo?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int small(int frecuencia[], int n, int i);


void swap(int frecuencia[], int i, int j){
    int temp=frecuencia[i];
    frecuencia[i]=frecuencia[j];
    frecuencia[j]=temp;
}

int partition(int frecuencia[],int l, int r){
    
    int pivot=frecuencia[r];
    int i=l-1;
    
    for(int j=l;j<r;j++){
        if(frecuencia[j]<pivot){
            i++;
            swap(frecuencia,i,j);
        }
    }
    swap(frecuencia,i+1,r);
    return i+1;
}

void quicksort(int frecuencia[], int l, int r){
    
    if(l<r){
        
        int pi=partition(frecuencia,l,r);
        quicksort(frecuencia,l,pi-1);
        quicksort(frecuencia,pi+1,r);
    }
}


int main()
{
    //declaramos e inicializamos array
    string busquedasFrecuentes[] ={"2d arrays","matrices","algoritmos", "arrays c++", "C++ Multidimensional", "initialize 2d array", "center elements","2d array as element", "matriz bidimensional","too many initializers","0x6ffdf0 error c++","c++ beginners","error initializers char","combining 2d array","random number list generator","multidimensional arrays","c++ matriz 2 arrays","llenar matriz letras","multidimensional char array","c++ matrix bidimensional"};
    int frecuencia [] = {152,5,5,842,476,438,65,152,148,4,16,5,634,634,120,16,729,148,83,645};    
    int i, j;
    int pos,temp,pass=0;
    int opcion;
    int k, index, t;
    bool repetir = true;
    
    do {
        system("cls");
        
        // Opciones en pantallas del menu principal
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\tMenu de Opciones" << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\t----------------" << endl;
        cout << "\n\t1. Burbuja" << endl;
        cout << "\t2. Insercion" << endl;
        cout << "\t3. Seleccion" << endl;
        cout << "\t4. Quicksort" << endl;
        cout << "\t0. Salir" << endl;
        
        cout << " Selecciona una opcion: ";
        cin >> opcion;
        
        int numero1, numero2;
        float resultado;
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                // Instrucciones para metodo de busqueda de burbuja
                
                
                cout <<"Lista ingresada ...\n";
                   for(i = 0; i<20; i++) {
                      cout <<frecuencia[i]<<"\t";
                   }
                cout<<endl;
                for(i = 0; i<20; i++) {
                   for(j = i+1; j<20; j++)
                       {
                          if(frecuencia[j] < frecuencia[i]) {
                             temp = frecuencia[i];
                             frecuencia[i] = frecuencia[j];
                             frecuencia[j] = temp;
                          }
                       }
                    pass++;
                }
                cout <<"Lista ordenada ...\n";
                for(i = 0; i<20; i++) {
                   cout << "    "  << busquedasFrecuentes [i]<< "     " <<frecuencia[i]<< sizeof(4) << endl;
                   
                }
                cout<<"\nNumero de ciclos usados para ordenar la lista:"<<pass<<endl; //
                
                
                system("pause>nul");
                break;
                
            case 2:
                // Instrucciones para metodo de busqueda por insercion
                
                
                
                system("pause>nul");
                break;
                
            case 3:
                // Instrucciones para metodo de busqueda por seleccion   
                cout << "Elementos no ordenados: \n" <<endl;
                for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                cout<<busquedasFrecuentes [i] << "     " <<frecuencia[i]<<endl;
                }
                for( i = 0;i < 20; i++)
                {
                index = small(frecuencia, 20, i);
                t = frecuencia[i];
                frecuencia[i] = frecuencia[index];
                frecuencia[index] = t;
                }
                cout << "\n\nElementos ordenados:  \n" <<endl;
                for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                cout<< busquedasFrecuentes [i] << "     " <<frecuencia[i]<<endl;
                }
                return 0;
                }
                int small(int frecuencia[], int n, int i)
                {  //error function definition is nor allowed here berfor { token
                int s, index, j;
                s = frecuencia[i];
                index = i;
                for( j = i+1; j < 20; j++)
                {
                if(frecuencia[j] < s )
                {
                s = frecuencia[j];
                index = j;
                }
                }
                return index;
                }
            
                system("pause>nul");
                break;
                
            case 4:
                // Instrucciones para metodo de busqueda quicksort
                quicksort(frecuencia,0,19);
                for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
                    cout << busquedasFrecuentes[i]<< "    - " <<frecuencia[i]<<" ";
                    {cout<<endl;
                    }
                }
                cout<<"\nNumero de ciclos usados para ordenar la lista:"<<pass<<endl; 
                
                system("pause>nul");     
                break;
            
            case 0:
                repetir = false;
                break;
        }        
    } while (repetir);
     
    return 0;

} //expected } at end of input, error while at the end, error expedted{, error expedted; , error exp}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Alguna ayuda para saber que podria estar omitiendo?

Algunos consejos:

- Tabular bien el código: Esto te ayuda a evitar problemas como los de las llaves faltantes
- Se coherente al escribir código: Si en cada `for` (por poner un ejemplo), pones las llaves en sitios diferentes (final de línea, nueva línea sin tabular, nueva línea tabulada, ...) es más dificil localizar errores como los que comentas

Aplicando estas dos premisas el código ya quedaría así:

```
int main()
{
    //declaramos e inicializamos array
    string busquedasFrecuentes[] = {
        "2d arrays", "matrices", "algoritmos", "arrays c++", "C++ Multidimensional",
        "initialize 2d array", "center elements","2d array as element", "matriz bidimensional",
        "too many initializers", "0x6ffdf0 error c++", "c++ beginners",
        "error initializers char", "combining 2d array", "random number list generator",
        "multidimensional arrays", "c++ matriz 2 arrays", "llenar matriz letras",
        "multidimensional char array", "c++ matrix bidimensional"
    };

    int frecuencia [] = {
        152, 5,   5, 842, 476, 438,  65, 152, 148,   4,
         16, 5, 634, 634, 120,  16, 729, 148,  83, 645
    };    
    int i, j;
    int pos,temp,pass=0;
    int opcion;
    int k, index, t;
    bool repetir = true;
    
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        
        // Opciones en pantallas del menu principal
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\tMenu de Opciones" << endl;
        cout << "\t\t\t----------------" << endl;
        cout << "\n\t1. Burbuja" << endl;
        cout << "\t2. Insercion" << endl;
        cout << "\t3. Seleccion" << endl;
        cout << "\t4. Quicksort" << endl;
        cout << "\t0. Salir" << endl;
        
        cout << " Selecciona una opcion: ";
        cin >> opcion;
        
        int numero1, numero2;
        float resultado;
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case 1:
                // Instrucciones para metodo de busqueda de burbuja
                
                cout <<"Lista ingresada ...\n";
                for(i = 0; i<20; i++)
                {
                    cout <<frecuencia[i]<<"\t";
                }
                cout<<endl;
                for(i = 0; i<20; i++)
                {
                    for(j = i+1; j<20; j++)
                    {
                        if(frecuencia[j] < frecuencia[i])
                        {
                            temp = frecuencia[i];
                            frecuencia[i] = frecuencia[j];
                            frecuencia[j] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                    pass++;
                }
                cout <<"Lista ordenada ...\n";
                for(i = 0; i<20; i++)
                {
                    cout << "    "  << busquedasFrecuentes [i]<< "     " 
                         << frecuencia[i] << sizeof(4) << endl;
                }
                cout<<"\nNumero de ciclos usados para ordenar la lista:"<<pass<<endl; //
                                    
                system("pause>nul");
                break;
                
            case 2:
                // Instrucciones para metodo de busqueda por insercion
                
                system("pause>nul");
                break;
                
            case 3:
                // Instrucciones para metodo de busqueda por seleccion   
                cout << "Elementos no ordenados: \n" <<endl;
                for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    cout<<busquedasFrecuentes [i] << "     " <<frecuencia[i]<<endl;
                }
                for( i = 0;i < 20; i++)
                {
                    index = small(frecuencia, 20, i);
                    t = frecuencia[i];
                    frecuencia[i] = frecuencia[index];
                    frecuencia[index] = t;
                }
                cout << "\n\nElementos ordenados:  \n" <<endl;
                for(i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                {
                    cout<< busquedasFrecuentes [i] << "     " <<frecuencia[i]<<endl;
                }
                return 0;
            } // <<---- ESTA LLAVE SOBRA

                int small(int frecuencia[], int n, int i)
                {  // error function definition is nor allowed here berfor { token
                    int s, index, j;
                    s = frecuencia[i];
                    index = i;
                    for( j = i+1; j < 20; j++)
                    {
                        if(frecuencia[j] < s )
                        {
                            s = frecuencia[j];
                            index = j;
                        }
                    }
                    return index;
                }
            
                system("pause>nul"); //// <<---- Este código está tras un return
                break;               //// <<---- No se ejecutará nunca
                
            case 4:
                // Instrucciones para metodo de busqueda quicksort
                quicksort(frecuencia,0,19);
                for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
                {
                    cout << busquedasFrecuentes[i]<< "    - " <<frecuencia[i]<<" ";
                    {  // <<---- No hay if, do, for, .... esta llave sobra
                        cout<<endl;
                    }  // <<---- Esta llave sobra
                 }

                cout<<"\nNumero de ciclos usados para ordenar la lista:"<<pass<<endl; 
                
                system("pause>nul");     
                break;
            
            case 0:
                repetir = false;
                break;
        }        
    } while (repetir);
     
    return 0;

}
```

Fíjate como aplicando estas dos reglas el error ha salido solo (comentario en mayúsculas). Adicionalmente han salido a la luz un par de detalles que, con tu código original, era complicado de ver.

En cuanto al error de

> error function definition is nor allowed here berfor { token

Este error se está produciendo porque C++ no admite funciones anidadas. Fíjate que donde se está produciendo el error estás definiendo una función... y además esa función estaría dentro de otra (la función `main`)

La solución es simple: Coloca la función `small` fuera del `main`

```
int small()
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Gracias eferion ya hice algunas correcciones como me señalabas, también acomode la indentacion.

Aunque ahora me muestra 2 errores, que no se porque 
C:\Users\.....collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status


C:\Users....Local\Temp\cc8xXDIs.o file.cpp:(.text+0xb34): undefined reference to `small(int*, int, int)'

Comment: @Acidous undefiend reference es porque no encuentra la definición de la función `small`. Eso suele suceder porque el linker no es capaz de encontrar la definición de la función. Sin código es complicado darte una respuesta más concreta. Ese problema se merece una pregunta independiente